# Missing Text Messages?

Tags: iphone, messages

I've got a little problem with my text messages; here's the background...

I had texted the family the night before but woke up with my phone dead. Once I had charged the phone to the point where it was able to turn on again, I saw various notifications which I had received whilst the phone had been dead. One of these notifications was a reply from the relative I had texted the night before, and although it only displayed their number (due to start up, contact names are not shown yet) I knew it was them. I could also see the preview of the message.

When I unlock my phone for the first time and check my Messages app the actual message is nowhere to be seen. I've tried manually searching for the message, restarted the phone many times but no luck. My Messages still works and I am able to still send and receive but I'd like to find this missing message.

Comment: Could you please add your iOS version to this question? I am experiencing this issue on iOS 11 PB1, and thought it was a beta issue.

Comment: I'm on IOS 10.3.2